# Database, Column name in other language

Tags: sql, database

May I ask is there any cautions to set column name other than English?

Within same code utf8, I tried to set the column name to other language, it could create and look like running with no problems. However, I want to know if is it common particle or any cautions that I should consider?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your column names should be clear to the people who have to write queries against that table.

Comment: Yes, so if the user is foreigner..then? is it that mean it is the correct way to set the name in his language?

Comment: MY concern is about is there an unexpected error by doing so...

Comment: Unexpected like mistyping it?  I do that in my own language.

Comment: No, more like will probably crash the server or etc... I don't know so asking...

Comment: @Cong Xu brought up a good point about non standard characters.  For example, some languages have accented characters, such as ç.  These will either work or fail 100% of the time.  Therefore, try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for keywords and forbidden characters, column names can be anything you want.

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(Column1 int,
 Column2 float,
 kjsdahflskayfabvfalkhhg varchar(20))
```

is a perfectly valid table schema. It is also largely useless.

Computers are fine with this because they only deal with *syntax*. People on the other hand have to deal with *semantics* (i.e. what does it *mean*) as well.

```
The apple ate the man.
```

and

```
The man ate the apple.
```

are both correct English *syntactically* but only the second one is correct *semantically*, because the first describes an impossible situation.

To your question, table and column names should make sense to the people that use them. If the majority the **users of your database** speak Swahili then use Swahili words. Let the presentation layer guys worry about how to display this to **users of your application** in their native language. High level programming languages have whole libraries dedicated to this.

If you force the database programmers to work in a language other than their native one then you adding another opportunity for people to make mistakes in translating their thoughts into code.

**However**, if there is a good reason for a *lingua franca* like:

- It’s a contractual obligation
- The program is for an English speaking client
- The program has a global workforce

then English is probably your best choice.

Comment: I don't think the problem is having non-English column names, but rather column names that use characters outside the Latin alphabet.